# Jobutil main loop protection error

Tags: python, fork, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting an error heeding me to protect my main loop, even though I'm protecting my main loop. The skeleton of my code:

```
from sklearn.learning_curve import learning_curve
...

def runit():

...
    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
        DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced'), X, y, cv=5, 
        train_sizes=train_sizes, n_jobs=4)

...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    runit()
```

I get the error for the line where I run the `learning_curve`:

> ImportError: [joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing without
>   protecting your import on a system that does not support forking. To
>   use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect your main loop
>   using "if **name** == '**main**'". Please see the joblib documentation
>   on Parallel for more information

Which is weird, because a) I am protecting the main loop and b) I'm running on a Mac, and as a UNIX-based system, forking IS supported. What am I missing? Using Python 3 in a Jupyter notebook, code does not give the error when I use `n_jobs=1`.